# how to increase the scrollview height with gridview inside in android

Tags: java, android, xml

current -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJin0.jpg

**how to increase the scrollview height in android**

I want to make a screen that scrolls continuously with a gridview in the remaining space below.

code

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Make scrollview ->  android:layout_height="match_parent" and  android:fillViewport="false"

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView2"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
android:paddingStart="20dp"
android:paddingEnd="20dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:scrollbars="none">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Try this, it might work.